Lost atoms in a lammps simulation
I am simulating the thermal conductance along the z axis for bilayer graphene sandwiched by Al2O3 system. This is my input setting.
variable x equal 47.59
variable y equal 41.214148966101
variable z equal 136.636
variable t equal 300.0

#Setup parameters
units real
atom_style atomic
read_data atomic_structure_atomic
mass 1 16.0
mass 2 27.0
mass 3 12.0
mass 4 12.0
velocity all create $t 87287

pair_style hybrid/overlay lj/cut 12.0 morse 6.287 tersoff shift -0.0462
pair_coeff 1 1 lj/cut 0.194633996 3.541
pair_coeff 1 2 lj/cut 0.31351524159 4.02
pair_coeff 1 3 lj/cut 0.0 1
pair_coeff 1 4 lj/cut 0.0 1
pair_coeff 2 2 lj/cut 0.50500834301 4.499
pair_coeff 2 3 morse 10.81786819 1.738 2.246
pair_coeff 2 4 morse 10.81786819 1.738 2.246
pair_coeff * * tersoff ./Copt.tersoff NULL NULL C C

neighbor 0.3 bin
neigh_modify delay 0 every 1

#layers for heat flux
region hot block INF INF INF INF 28.69356 41.810616
region cold block INF INF INF INF 96.32838 97.01156
compute Thot all temp/region hot
compute Tcold all temp/region cold

#1st equilibirum run
fix 1 all nvt temp $t $t 100.0
thermo 1
run 3000000
velocity all scale $t
unfix 1

#2nd equilibrium run
fix 1 all nve
fix hot all heat 1 23.0609 region hot
fix cold all heat 1 -23.0609 region cold
thermo_style custom step temp c_Thot c_Tcold
thermo_modify colname c_Thot Temp_hot colname c_Tcold Temp_cold
thermo 10
run 10000

#thermal conductivity calculation
compute ke all ke/atom
variable temp atom c_ke/23.0609/1.5/8.617333262145e-5
compute layers all chunk/atom bin/1d z lower 1.0 units reduced
fix 2 all ave/chunk 10 100 1000 layers v_temp file profile.heat
variable tdiff equal f_2[20][3]-f_2[36][3]
fix ave all ave/time 1 1 1000 v_tdiff ave running start 13000

variable kappa equal 23.0609/(lx*ly)*lz/f_ave
thermo_style custom step temp c_Thot c_Tcold v_tdiff f_ave
thermo_modify colname c_Thot Temp_hot colname c_Tcold Temp_cold &
              colname v_tdiff dTemp_step colname f_ave dTemp

run 3000000
print "Running average thermal conductivity: $(v_kappa:%.4f)"

This is the error message I received after I launched the calculation.
LAMMPS (2 Aug 2023 - Update 1)
variable x equal 47.59
variable y equal 41.214148966101
variable z equal 136.636
variable t equal 300.0

#Setup parameters
units real
atom_style atomic
read_data atomic_structure_atomic
Reading data file ...
  triclinic box = (0 0 0) to (47.59 41.214149 136.636) with tilt (-23.795 0 0)
WARNING: Triclinic box skew is large. LAMMPS will run inefficiently. (../domain.cpp:220)
  2 by 2 by 8 MPI processor grid
  reading atoms ...
  19600 atoms
  read_data CPU = 0.131 seconds
mass 1 16.0
mass 2 27.0
mass 3 12.0
mass 4 12.0
velocity all create $t 87287
velocity all create 300 87287

#pair_style hybrid/overlay lj/cut 10.0 morse 6.287 tersoff shift -0.0462 kolmogorov/crespi/z 20.0
pair_style hybrid/overlay lj/cut 12.0 morse 6.287 tersoff shift -0.0462
pair_coeff 1 1 lj/cut 0.194633996 3.541
pair_coeff 1 2 lj/cut 0.31351524159 4.02
pair_coeff 1 3 lj/cut 0.0 1
pair_coeff 1 4 lj/cut 0.0 1
pair_coeff 2 2 lj/cut 0.50500834301 4.499
pair_coeff 2 3 morse 10.81786819 1.738 2.246
pair_coeff 2 4 morse 10.81786819 1.738 2.246
pair_coeff * * tersoff ./Copt.tersoff NULL NULL C C

neighbor 0.3 bin
neigh_modify delay 0 every 1

#layers for heat flux
region hot block INF INF INF INF 28.69356 41.810616
region cold block INF INF INF INF 96.32838 97.01156
compute Thot all temp/region hot
compute Tcold all temp/region cold

#1st equilibirum run
fix 1 all nvt temp $t $t 100.0
fix 1 all nvt temp 300 $t 100.0
fix 1 all nvt temp 300 300 100.0
thermo 1
run 3000000
Neighbor list info ...
  update: every = 1 steps, delay = 0 steps, check = yes
  max neighbors/atom: 2000, page size: 100000
  master list distance cutoff = 12.3
  ghost atom cutoff = 12.3
  binsize = 6.15, bins = 12 7 23
  6 neighbor lists, perpetual/occasional/extra = 6 0 0
  (1) pair lj/cut, perpetual, skip from (4)
      attributes: half, newton on
      pair build: skip
      stencil: none
      bin: none
  (2) pair morse, perpetual, skip from (5)
      attributes: half, newton on, cut 6.587
      pair build: skip
      stencil: none
      bin: none
  (3) pair tersoff, perpetual, skip from (6)
      attributes: full, newton on, cut 2.4
      pair build: skip
      stencil: none
      bin: none
  (4) neighbor class addition, perpetual
      attributes: half, newton on
      pair build: half/bin/newton/tri
      stencil: half/bin/3d/tri
      bin: standard
  (5) neighbor class addition, perpetual, trim from (4)
      attributes: half, newton on, cut 6.587
      pair build: trim
      stencil: none
      bin: none
  (6) neighbor class addition, perpetual
      attributes: full, newton on, cut 2.4
      pair build: full/bin/atomonly
      stencil: full/bin/3d
      bin: standard
Per MPI rank memory allocation (min/avg/max) = 6.496 | 8.707 | 10.81 Mbytes
   Step          Temp          E_pair         E_mol          TotEng         Press     
         0   300            4.3067738e+08  0              4.306949e+08   4.4405907e+08
         1   9.6397316e-73  2.5266396e+09  0              2.5266396e+09  2.5914761e+09
ERROR: Lost atoms: original 19600 current 19595 (../thermo.cpp:488)
Last command: run 3000000

I checked the unit for the potential and energy settings. It is said that the metal units would be converted into real unit by LAMMPS for the tersoff potential automatically. I did not changed the tersoff potential and only change the unit for energy from eV to Kcal/mol in the lj and mose potential.
I think that the force was not that large to blow up some atoms out of the unit cell. I do not understand why I still receive this error message.
Would anyone please give me some suggestions/comments on the parameter settings in my input file?
Thank you in advance.

You have extremely high pressure, which means that (i) either your periodic boundary conditions are wrong, and (or) (ii) you have not minimized your system properly. While we are at it, I would also request you to check if your parameters are correct, since you mention that the units were converted. It might also happen that your system is very small, and you are running on multiple CPU cores leading to lost atoms.

Too many processors / too few atoms per processor typically gives a segmentation fault, not lost atoms. Plus, the first step did compute. I would recommend (a) checking for units by doing everything in units metal and re-parameterizing the pair-styles as needed (b) checking that there are no overlapping atoms to start with, e.g., delete_atoms with a cutoff (c) pre-relaxing before starting NVT. I typically do an energy minimization first, then a fix box/relax, and only then start dynamics.

Also see if these questions / answers help you to troubleshoot your issue:
https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1383/4515
https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11696/4515
https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9889/4515

@Hemanth Haridas Thank you for your suggestions. I switched to metal unit and the error was gone. Based on your suggestions, does the CPU core number matter a lot in the LAMMPS simulation? Is there any thumb rule to choose the core number for MPI run? Thank you again.

@Andrey Poletayev Thank you very much for your helpful suggestion. I switched to metal unit and adopted the pre-relaxing scheme; then, the 'lost atom' error was gone. In your opinion, is the thermal stabilization in the NVT ensemble not enough to equilibrate this 'Al2O3-bilayer graphene-Al2O3' system under the room temperature?

@Kieran the thermalization with NVT is still necessary - it is just safer to do it after a static, effectively zero-Kelvin relaxation rather than upfront.

@Kieran regarding the processor counts, this has to do with how LAMMPS parallelizes the computation and depends on your simulation cell and radial cutoffs chosen for pair_styles. The telltale sign of "too many CPUs for the system" is a segmentation fault - not what you have here. There is not a heuristic beyond "give it as many CPUs as you have without segmentation faults". LAMMPS is pretty good at parallelizing, but that is a separate discussion. For that, you can ask a separate question, e.g., "how do I determine the optimum or largest number of CPUs to assign a LAMMPS simulation?"
